# I'm getting exception in report definition, My properties mapped into external mysql DB,

Tags: pega, fiware-pegasus

I'm getting exception in report definition, My properties mapped into external mysql DB, When i was run the report definition, this exception occurred

Error:

** An error occured on executing the query for the report definition - There was a problem getting a list: code: 1064 SQLState: 42000 Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`customerid` AS "customerid" , "PC0".`customername` AS "customername" FROM TELE' at line 1 DatabaseException caused by prior exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`customerid` AS "customerid" , "PC0".`customername` AS "customername" FROM TELE' at line 1 | SQL Code: 1064 | SQL State: 42000

this is db query on tracer "SELECT "PC0".`customerid` AS "customerid" , "PC0".`customername` AS "customername" FROM TELECOMMUNICATION.bsstest "PC0" "

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com ask db related question at db stackexchange

Comment: Are you sure that class property names and db column names are same ? I mean if db column name is `customerid` then the class property should also have to be `customerid`.

Comment: Yes, both are same, I have run that query  directly from the mysql db. i think this error occurred in " PC0" part. db query is "SELECT "PC0".customerid AS "customerid" , "PC0".customername AS "customername" FROM TELECOMMUNICATION.bsstest "PC0" "

Answer (score 0):

I guess MySQL doesn't recognize the alias with quotes around it. You need to follow up with PEGA regarding this.